# Have WSDL to a number of services - how pass around authentication?

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I have two web services that I made references to in a VS 2010 C# project.  One of the services does authentication, the other does work getting data.
( I can also generate the classes using WSDL, but the web references seem equivalent).

I authenticate with service 1, but how then do I tell the other service that I'm authenticated?  There is a cookie generated by service 1 that I see in Fiddler, but I do not see how to get at it as I am not using any of the basic Http classes.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I see the answer now.  Each of my WSDL-generated objects has a CookieCollection which I can read from service1 after the authentication call.  Then I can set the cookies for the second the second service like so:

```
response = service1.Authenticate();
CookieCollection allCookies= service1.CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri);
foreach (Cookie c in allCookies)
{
  service2.CookieContainer.SetCookies(_uri,c.Name + "=" +  c.Value);
}
service2.CallMyMethod();
```

That seems to be the gist of it.